# Measure-Command or StopWatch Returning Confusing/Inaccurate Results

Tags: performance, powershell, authentication, vbscript

I am trying to improve the performance of a powershell logon script which I am converting from VBS, and have come across a problem in my testing.

I wrote the following test to try and find the fastest way of retrieving all drives connected to the current machine:

```
################################################################# PSDrive
Measure-Command { Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' }

$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'

$sw.Stop()
$elapsed =  $sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
write-host $elapsed
############################################################# END PSDrive

##################################################################### WMI
Measure-Command { Get-WMIObject -query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4" }

$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

Get-WMIObject -query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4"

$sw.Stop()
$elapsed =  $sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
write-host $elapsed
################################################################# END WMI
```

As you can see I am using 2 different methods to retrieve the drives :

`Get-PSDrive`

`Get-WMIObject`

I am also using 2 different techniques to measure the speed of each command:

`Measure-Command`

`[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()`

However, each of the 2 drive-retrieval techniques is measured as faster depending on which method is used to measure the time taken. This is some sample output from the above script (I've just included the relevant details):

> **Get-PSDrive**
>
> Measure Command (TotalMilliseconds) : 0.6983
>
> Stopwatch       (TotalMilliseconds) : 408.9745
>
> **Get-WMIObject**
>
> Measure Command (TotalMilliseconds) : 46.8607
>
> Stopwatch       (TotalMilliseconds) : 158.0209

Stopwatch       (TotalMilliseconds) : 158.0209

---

So my question is, which one (if any) is more reliable? Or is trying to measure my code in this way a total waste of time? Much appreciate any help on this.

---

**Update**

Amended the code to send each command into a variable (e.g. `$x = Get-PSDrive -PsProvider 'FileSystem'`), and now the output makes a lot more sense:

> **Get-PSDrive**
>
> Measure Command (TotalMilliseconds) : 0.6983
>
> Stopwatch       (TotalMilliseconds) : 408.9745
>
> **Get-WMIObject**
>
> Measure Command (TotalMilliseconds) : 46.8607
>
> Stopwatch       (TotalMilliseconds) : 158.0209

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Measure-Command` will discard the pipeline output, measuring only the time it takes to actually execute the command.

The stopwatch timer is measuring the time it takes to execute the command and then display all of the output to the console.

To get `Measure-Command` to measure the time needed to write to the console, add an explicit pipe to `Out-Host` inside the script block you're measuring. You should then see the output written to the console, and a corresponding increase in the measured time to complete.

Comment: This seems correct - thanks Mjolinor. Do you know if there is a way of getting Measure-Command to capture the time taken to print to the console? When I measure `$x = [statement]; $x` it still only seems to measure the first part, and doesn't account for the part which is writing to the screen

Comment: Add an explicit pipe to Out-Host inside the script block you're measuring. You should then see the output written to the console, and a corresponding increase in the measured time to complete.